# Vectorize scalar function calls using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, color-mapping

I'd like to use colorsys module to convert between RGB and HSL.
However, colorsys API is scalar-based.
I wonder how I can vectorize it without for-loop so that I can do something like

```
hsl = np.vstack([np.ones((1, 256)), np.ones((1, 256,)), np.ones((1, 256,))]).transpose()
rgb = colorsys.hls_to_rgb(hsl[0, :], hsl[1, :], hsl[2, :])
```

Comment: np.vectorize will do it but it just hides the loop from you, it won't be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `np.vectorize`, but as lolopop points out, this simply adds syntactic sugar; it does not make the implicit loop any faster:

```
import colorsys
import numpy as np
rgb_to_hls = np.vectorize(colorsys.rgb_to_hls)
hls_to_rgb = np.vectorize(colorsys.hls_to_rgb)

arr = np.random.random((2, 2, 3)) * 255
r, g, b = arr[:, :, 0], arr[:, :, 1], arr[:, :, 2]
h, l, s = rgb_to_hls(r, g, b)
r2, g2, b2 = hls_to_rgb(h, l, s)
arr2 = np.dstack([r2, g2, b2])
assert np.allclose(arr, arr2)
```